# js use "Chain of Responsibility Pattern" but after export, all external calls are empty

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I am trying to implement "Chain of Responsibility Pattern" with JS, but the problem I encountered, after exporting "chainController", all external calls got NULL. From the code point of view, there is no asynchronous problem, which makes me very confused , please help me, very thankful

code:

```js
/** Chain **/
const Chain = function(handler) {
  this.handler = handler;
  this.nextHandler = null;
}

Chain.prototype.setNextHandler = function(nextHandler) {
  this.nextHandler = nextHandler;
  return nextHandler;
}

Chain.prototype.pass = function(...args) {
  const result = this.handler(...args);
  if (result === 'next') {
    return this.nextHandler && this.nextHandler.pass(...args);
  }
  return result;
}

/** Handlers **/
const equalTen = function(number) {
  return (number === 10) ? 'equal-ten' : 'next';
}

const equalTwenty = function(number) {
  return (number === 20) ? 'equal-twenty' : 'next';
}

const equalThirty = function(number) {
  return (number === 30) ? 'equal-thirty' : 'next';
}

/** Controller **/
const chainController = function(number) {
  const checkEqualTen = new Chain(equalTen);
  const checkEqualTwenty = new Chain(equalTwenty);
  const checkEqualThirty = new Chain(equalThirty);

  checkEqualTen
    .setNextHandler(checkEqualTwenty)
    .setNextHandler(checkEqualThirty);

  return checkEqualTen.pass(number);
};

//is problem, when external call him, always get null
let test = chainController(15);
console.log(test);
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ddbuv4?file=index.js)

Comment: No need for the stackblitz - please use [StackSnippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: Aren't you handling only for 10, 20 and 30 in this case? So `let test = chainController(10);` should give you "equal-ten"

Comment: thank you, I found that I made a stupid mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs since you call next from within the last in the chain (checkEqualThirty()) - But there is no next, so the default answer assignment to `nextHandler` is `null` - hence `null` is returned and console.logged.

You've left yourself no escape route. I've modified the code so you accommodate other possibilities in the pass method.

```js
/** Chain **/
const Chain = function(handler) {
  this.handler = handler;
  this.nextHandler = null;
}

Chain.prototype.setNextHandler = function(nextHandler) {
  this.nextHandler = nextHandler;
  return nextHandler;
}

Chain.prototype.pass = function(...args) {
  let result = this.handler(...args);
  if (result === 'next' && this.nextHandler !== null) {
    result = this.nextHandler.pass(...args);
  } else if (result === 'next') {
    result = "Not found";
  }
  return result;
}

/** Handlers **/
const equalTen = function(number) {
  return (number === 10) ? 'equal-ten' : 'next';
}

const equalTwenty = function(number) {
  return (number === 20) ? 'equal-twenty' : 'next';
}

const equalThirty = function(number) {
  return (number === 30) ? 'equal-thirty' : 'next';
}

/** Controller **/
const chainController = function(number) {
  const checkEqualTen = new Chain(equalTen);
  const checkEqualTwenty = new Chain(equalTwenty);
  const checkEqualThirty = new Chain(equalThirty);

  checkEqualTen
    .setNextHandler(checkEqualTwenty)
    .setNextHandler(checkEqualThirty);

  return checkEqualTen.pass(number);
};

//is problem, when external call him, always get null
console.log(chainController(5));
console.log(chainController(10));
console.log(chainController(15));
console.log(chainController(20));
console.log(chainController(25));
console.log(chainController(30));
console.log(chainController(35));
```